# Flyway - Postgresql partitioned table

Tags: postgresql, flyway

I would like to generate partitioned table on PostgreSQL 11 database using Flyway. When I try to execute simple SQL file like

```sql
CREATE TABLE blabla (id varchar(100) NOT NULL, name varchar(100) NULL) 
PARTITION BY LIST(name);
```

I have an error saying that "PARTITION" is not validate even if  I'm using last release of flyway core library.
Does anyone know if partitioned table on PostgreSQL are managed with Flyway or what is the correct way for partition table creation ?

Comment: Can you give the full error stack trace? It appears to work correctly for me in our test environment.

Comment: Also, a copy of the actual migration would help - if you don't want to post publically then you can mail to support@red-gate.com

Comment: @JuliaHayward I have sent full stack and sql script to support red gate